# Ruby encode UTF-8 string to UTF-16

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

I want to store the UTF-16 encoding into another variable as UTF-8 string.

```
1.9.3p194 :117 > str = "سلام"
 => "سلام" 
1.9.3p194 :118 > enc = str.encode("utf-16")
 => "\uFEFF\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645" 
1.9.3p194 :119 > puts enc
??3D'E
 => nil
```

I want to store `\uFEFF\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645` (not `??3D'E`) into a UTF-8 string so I can be able to concatenate it with other UTF-8 strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-inspect):

```
str = "سلام"
# => "سلام"
enc = str.encode("utf-16")
# => "\uFEFF\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645"
puts enc
# output: ▒▒3D'E
# => nil
puts enc.inspect
# output: "\uFEFF\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645"
# => nil
```